# Fabric windows client put command not converting directory separators when target is Linux

Tags: python, fabric

I have a fabfile that I run on Windows.  I am using the put(...) command to move files where the target OS is Linux...

```
put('*', '/home/somedir/')
```

The result is I get on the target Linux system...

```
/home/somedir/directoryFromWindows\\file
```

So fabric does not seem to realize the client is windows but the target is Linux and the directory separators are not being converted from that DOS \ to the Linux /

Is there a technique that I can use to get this to work?  Where I work, some people are on Mac (unix) but others are on Windows.  The fabfile put (or course) works find going Mac -> Linux, but the fabfile put going from Windows -> Linux has the above issue.

Any suggestions?

UPDATE:

Ok, it seems the problem is that the directory tree on windows was created via an svn checkout so there are those .svn directories all over the place.  Fabric seems to be escaping the . e.g. if I do a

```
put('*' , /targetDir)
```

fabric is constructing a path like

```
somepath\\.svn
```

when it encounters an .svn directory anywhere in the tree.  I have been trying to use globbing to negate all files and directories that have .svn

```
put( !(.svn), /targetDir)
```

Does anyone know how to **correctly** use globbing so all the .svn directories in the tree will be excluded?  This, I think, will solve the problem

Comment: This strange behavior should be reported as a bug.